Spirit of the Beehive: painting in the father's study
In The Spirit of the Beehive (1973), the father has a painting behind the desk in his study. It's of an old, bearded man in either a red toga or perhaps priestly vestments, sitting at a desk, writing with a quill. A lion lurks in the background behind his write shoulder, and on the desk near his left hand is a skull.

The painting is centrally placed in several scenes, and gets "studied" by the camera in a montage of extreme close-ups around 57 minutes into the movie.
What is the painting of? Is he man supposed to be the evangelist Mark (thus the lion)? Who painted it? What does having this painting in his study say about the father and how he thinks of himself?

This is an (unsigned) 17th or 18th Century painting of St Jerome in his Study, a common enough theme for renaissance painters that it's been recreated repeatedly. The style is strikingly similar to that of Jusepe de Ribera, but it doesn't appear to be by him. Possibly a pupil or just an admirer.
Presumably the painting in the film is a print since the actual painting is in private ownership at a monastery in France.


St. Jerome is famous for translating the bible into Latin. Legend has it that he pulled a thorn from the paw of a lion and it became his constant companion. I can't see how either of those would be especially relevant to what's happening on screen.
Thematically, I think it's just supposed to be evocative of someone studying hard in a study.

+1 Only had a quick search, but that's a tough find! There's a staggering amount of variations on the theme.

@blobbymcblobby - Not helped by the fact that this doesn't appear to have been publicly exhibited outside of the monastery.
